How to combine data rows with different naming conventions in Google sheets?
I have a table that looks like this:



Road
Accident




I-10
10


I-53
10


I-10 East
5


I-10/S
5



I'm looking for a way for the Accident counts are in for all versions of the I-10 and all other roads, so that the final table looks like this:



Road
Accident




I-10
20


I-53
10



There are also different naming conventions for the same road, such as:



Road
Accident




US STREET
10


US ST
10


5  AVENUE
5


5 AVE
5



And I'd like the table to look like



Road
Accident




US STREET
20


5 AVENUE
10



Thanks in advance for your help!
I looked at this thread which seemed helpful, but it did not include a way to sum up the values of the other column into one.

Using ARRAYFORMULA() with SUMIF() and SUBSTITUTE()
You can use this approach for better result and to get your expected result.
in Column C2 use this formula:
=IF(OR(A2 = "I-10 East", A2 = "I-10/S"), "I-10",
  IF(OR(A2 = "US ST", A2 = "US STREET"), "US STREET",
  IF(OR(A2 = "5 AVE", A2 = "5 AVENUE"), "5 AVENUE", A2)))


use that approach to standardized road names. Suppose your data starts in column A and your new column is C
For the Accident Counts you can use the Unique() and SUMIF() in Column E2 and F2
Cell E2:
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, "-", " ")))


Cell F2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, "-", " ")), E2:E, B2:B))


For the disabling the dash "-" you can use Substitute()
Cell D2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, "-", " "))


Reference:

SUBSTITUTE ()
UNIQUE function
IF function
ARRAYFORMULA ()
SUMIF()


Try QUERY() with REGEXEXTRACT().
=QUERY({INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4,"^[^ /]+")),B1:B4},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''")



Thanks, looks like that has taken care of most of them, but for some reason I am still seeing things like I-10E or I-10W. Does this mean that the formula combines anything after a slash or a space?
